# Don't show application layout on popup window using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, layout

I have a rails application using **views/layouts/application.html.erb** as the default site template.

I'm just about to add several popup windows. These shall not inherit and display the application template.

How can I **exclude several views** from loading the application template?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the action for those views render with layout false:

```
class YourController

  def popup
    render :layout => false
  end

end
```